# Qt Creator cannot find moveit headers

Tags: ros, moveit, headers, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My computer's OS is Ubuntu 12.04 with Groovy and I am working with the source installation of ros moveit. To modify one of the moveit packages I tried to open a package in qtcreator (execute qt creator from console --> 'open project' --> op Cmakelists) to benefit from code completion etc. However, I am facing two issues:

1. running cmake on package pr2_moveit_tutorials fails and I am receiving the following errors:
   CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (install):
   install TARGETS given no RUNTIME DESTINATION for executable target
   "planning_scene_tutorial".
   So far I circumvent this issue commenting out the 'target_link_library' lines in the Cmakelists. Perhaps cmake fails due to the catkin_make build system?
2. some headers cannot be found. The file 'motion_planning_interface_tutorial.cpp' contains the following headers:

include moveit/robot_model_loader/robot_model_loader.h
include moveit/planning_pipeline/planning_pipeline.h
include moveit/planning_interface/planning_interface.h
include moveit/kinematic_constraints/utils.h
include moveit_msgs/DisplayTrajectory.h
include moveit_msgs/PlanningScene.h

QT creator only finds the last two headers. In contrast to  moveit_msgs, 'moveit', is not really a package and that is probably the reason why QT creator cannot find the headers. Adding the following line to Cmakelists does not solve the issue...
include_directories(~/ros/workspace/moveit/src)
Any idea how to point QT Creator to the headers?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62313/qt-creator-cannot-find-moveit-headers/) by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2013-06-25**:
Did you use qt_ros to create your package ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you can move to ubunut 14.04 or 16.04 and to ros-indigo or kinect you can use the folowing [ros_qtc_pluggin](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_qtc_plugin/wiki/1.-How-to-Install-(Users))  to use qtcreator for ros developpement. It's quite simple to install and use

---

Originally posted by [adrienH](https://answers.ros.org/users/28141/adrienh/) with karma: 38 on 2017-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0